# Python - Unix commands not recognized in Jupyter

Tags: python, windows, git, jupyter

I have installed Git Bash, python 3.6 and Anaconda for the course which requires me to use Unix commands within Jupyter, such as !ls, !cat, !head etc.
However, for each of these commands I get (e.g.):

> 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I am using Windows 10. What can I do to be able to proceed with the course? 
Thanks!

Comment: Probably the easiest thing would be to just install some linux distro...

Comment: or install MSYS and put it in windows path

Comment: related: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8604 Looks like you don't have a lot of good options.

Comment: Thanks juanpa.arrivillaga, but I wouldn't want to be installing Linux for this...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, how do I put MSYS in windows path?

Comment: just add the path of `C:\msys64\usr\bin` (if msys was installed there)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , thank you very much. I have done what you said and it's working perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to be able to use Unix commands on Windows is to install MSYS.

Once installed, to be able to use the commands from any Windows / python prompt, supposing that MSYS is installed in `C:\msys64` (if you let default path untouched), add the following directory to user or system path:

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin
```

Comment: Git for Windows should have the MSYS binaries in its `usr\bin` directory.

Comment: probably, makes sense. This method is only a workaround when you did a botched/partial install.

Answer (score 12):

Please don't use !ls as mentioned in the course. 
Use %ls in the jupyter notebook and it works fine.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Jupyter Notebook in Windows run `conda install posix`.

It worked for me.